# menuitem.getmenuinfo is null in onContextItemSelected

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I have a `ScrollView` with an embedded `LinearLayout`, as suggested in the `ScrollView` documentation.  The following is a reduction of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab2_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I use the following pattern in many Activities that use a `ListView` instead of a `ScrollView`, with no issue.  So, the issue seems unique to ScrollView.

```
final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) frame.findViewById(R.id.tab2_view); 
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) frame.findViewById(R.id.top); 

//load and sort backing ArrayList

//neither of these calls resolve the issue
registerForContextMenu(scrollView);
//registerForContextMenu(layout);

//load layout with views
```

Here's where the issue occurs.  The value returned from `item.getMenuInfo()` is always null.

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        boolean result = false;
        try 
        {
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); //why is this null???
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { ExceptionHandler.handleException(LOG_TAG, e); }
        return result;
    }
```

Does anyone know how to resolve the issue?

I did find a work around in maintaining state variables, and checking against the `menuItem`'s title instead of the null `AdapterContextMenuInfo`.  But, I would prefer to understand how to get the `AdapterContextMenuInfo` from the selected `MenuItem`.

I've been through the SO posts.  They all seem to be rooted in copy/paste errors, or not calling `registerForContextMenu` on the correct object.  [This is the only article that suggests there's an issue aside from this.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7139)

Comment: @RiteshGune nothing is posted as a result of presenting the context menu.  What is it you want to see?

Comment: have find id for linear layout?

Comment: @PiyushGupta Oops.  I guess that's what I get for editing in the SO question view...I tried deleting the lines that were irrelevant to the issue; and failed. ;)  It's fixed now.

Comment: Ok...And yes..post logcat also at where you got error..